# Angle of View as one float

Tags: rotation

I found a piece of documentation that insists that a camera angle is stored in four bytes as a float. Is there a technical term for this? How can I encode XYZ Euler camera angles to a float that is in the IEEE-754 format that can somehow be decoded back to XYZ Euler camera angles?

For anyone who wants the documentation, it can be found here (look below "Camera Focus"): http://wiki.spinout182.com/w/Cutscenes

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Angle of View" is not a rotation angle, this is a property of camera optics. You might know it better by the term "Field of View," they mean the same thing (angle of view is a more descriptive term).

In computer graphics, when we talk of FOV we usually refer to the horizontal angle but it can be measured vertically or diagonally as well. Since the aspect ratio in a game like Zelda 64 is fixed, you only need one angle to define the camera's projection. This is why a single-precision floating-point variable is sufficient, in fact it is arguably overkill. The range of non-nauseating FOVs is very small.

#### Here is a great illustration showing why you only need one angle to define the projection when the aspect ratio is constant:

[image]

But since the article you linked to is on the implementation of a cutscene system, it makes sense to have a huge floating-point range between the FOV angles... gradually narrowing FOV is used quite often in Zelda games during the boss introduction sequence, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and the diagram! I take it Camera Roll says which axis to rotate along? In the cutscene format, the camera's location is simple, but this rotation is still a bit confusing. The in-game Debug Camera gives the camera rotation in terms of X, Y, and Z. I need a way to use these values within a cutscene because the views will need to be created by rotating along more than one axis. Is this where diagonal rotations come in? Is there a rotation algorithm anywhere that you know of? Thanks again! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @user2490045: Well, you are dealing with a data format here used to store cinematic sequences. It is quite likely that instead of storing the camera's orientation using euler angles, it is actually setup to store a reference location that the camera will "look at" for a particular key frame. There is a function known as `LookAt` in computer graphics that will orient a camera based at the eyepoint to focus on a particular location, it needs 1 additional bit of information to establish the camera's up direction (roll is what it seems to be called in the documentation you linked).

Comment: @user2490045: At any time in-between a key frame, interpolation would be used to determine these angles. Thus, you probably will not find the angles in the data file. It makes sense to do it this way if the camera is ever allowed to be positioned at an arbitrary location.